# AltBeacon lib: How to detect multiple beacons from different parsers simultaneousely

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon, eddystone

I have set the layout parsers for altBeacon, iBeacon and EddyStone beacons.

The region to scan all beacons is set to null, null, null.
When I have more types of beacons on the table, the app detects only one of them.
Alone the beacons are detected.

How can the altBeacon library detect multiple beacons from different parsers simultaneousely?

Comment: This should "just work".  Can you show your code?  There may be an issue with the setup.

Comment: Sorry, today it worked, but I can't say why.